# Update to androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0 causing 'indexOutOfBounds' crash

Tags: android, build.gradle, indexoutofboundsexception, android-appcompat, androidx

I recently updated my dependencies, including updating `androidx.appCompat` from `1.2.0` to `1.3.0`. It took some digging to figure out that this is what was causing my crash.
The crash doesn't occur until the user clicks on a MaterialCardView to transition to a new fragment on the home page.

Removing the dependency update resolved my issue. Does anyone know what in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0` might be causing this? Here's the crash log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at f.m.c.s0.v(FragmentTransitionImpl.java:3)
    at f.m.c.c.b(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:183)
    at f.m.c.x0.c(SpecialEffectsController.java:23)
    at f.m.c.b0.E(FragmentManager.java:81)
    at f.m.c.b0.Z(FragmentManager.java:11)
    at f.m.c.b0.C(FragmentManager.java:14)
    at f.m.c.b0$g.run(FragmentManager.java:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:10)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:7)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:4)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188457866 ?

Comment: Sure seems to be the same issue--thanks for sharing that @bwt!